# Excel VBA: Need to change my code to copy paste values in TEXT format

Tags: excel, vba

I have written VBA code in excel to copy a specific range on one tab and paste it to a new workbook which saves automatically.

However, the program I am inputting this file to is erroring because of one line that needs to be in text format. I am assuming I can just change the entire data set to text format and it would relieve my issues. The code is below. It has no other issues at the moment. I work at a public accounting firm so I have no idea what I am doing besides what I found on google.

```
Sub Reset()

Worksheets("Time Entry").Range("f11:j550").ClearContents

End Sub
Sub copypaste()

Set originalSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY")

    NewSheet.Range("a1:m490").Value = originalSheet.Range("q9:ac490").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:M").Columns.AutoFit
    
Dim lr As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 6 Step -1
Debug.Print i
If IsError(Range("c" & i).Value) Then

Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next i

 ActiveSheet.Move
    Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook
    
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Time Tracker\" & NewFileName & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Exit Sub

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

ErrorTrap:
MsgBox "Invalid directory. You must correct the path or save manually."
Resume Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Watch your language, please. This is a family and workspace friendly site.

Comment: With regard to your question, you can set the range's NumberFormat to `'@'`, which formats everything as text.

Comment: I don't know exactly where to insert this?

Comment: Right above the line where you're calling AutoFit, at the point you need to set all of the columns to text format.